# Implementation of the switch statement in C

Tags: c, switch-statement, implementation

How is a switch-case statement compiled/implemented in C.

Is it a linear lookup? Is it a hash table? Some other option?

If the specific compiler changes the answer, assume recent gcc version with no build flags.

In my situation the data is more that 50 sequential enums, so dense data.

Comment: Look at the compiled code. It probably depends on whether the case values are dense or sparse.

Comment: It's unlikely to be a hash table. For sparse values it's probably linear `if/else`, for dense values it's probably an indexed goto.

Comment: What@Barmar says.Plus: gcc sometimes generates a tree-like decision chain.

Comment: @FredLarson thanks for finding that.